# Change the WordPress > Error title?

Tags: customization

I am trying to change the title which is shown in Tabs/Windows when visiting a page you have no access to, where it now says "WordPress > Error".

This is how far I have come, but it doesn't work at all:

```
add_filter( 'wp_die_handler', 'change_die_wpse_120304' );
function change_die_wpse_120304()
{
    return 'do_wp_die_wpse_120304';
}

function do_wp_die_wpse_120304( $message, $title, $args )
{
    return 'Mynewtitle'.' &bull; '.$title.' &lsaquo; '.get_bloginfo('name'); 
}
```

I think wp_die_handler has something to do with this, but I cannot find any solution for this.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? When you say "when visiting a page you have no access to" do you mean a non-existent web page that ought to 404?  Or do you mean a part of the admin that you don't have permissions for?

Comment: A part of the admin you dont have permissions for. Sorry for not making it clear!

Answer (score 0):

The `wp_die_handler` filter filters the handler for the function responsible to kill the execution of the script. So it needs to return the callable that WordPress will use when `wp_die()` is called.

The actual callable that is returned from the `wp_die_handler` filter must output the error message and die.

```
function wpse_die( $message, $title = '', $args = [] ) {
  echo 'yolo';
  die;
}

function wpse_die_handler(){
  return 'wpse_die';
}
add_filter( 'wp_die_handler', 'wpse_die_handler' );
```

Have a look at [`_default_wp_die_handler()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_default_wp_die_handler/) for a look at what WordPress outputs from the default handler for `wp_die()`.

Comment: I tried inserting return 'Mynewtitle'.' &bull; '.$title.' &lsaquo; '.get_bloginfo('name');  where you put echo 'yolo'; but it doesn't work. I am not sure I understand what I am missing here.

Comment: You want to echo and die, not return.

Comment: So this is my new code:
  echo 'Mynewtitle'.' &bull; '.$title.' &lsaquo; '.get_bloginfo('name'); 
  die;
Still not working!

Comment: I have been trying everything for the last 2 hours without coming anywhere. How do I edit the title?